# Parsing error unexprected '*

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to make a script in `PHP` (using mariadb) that displays the amount of rows in a table and I'm trying to use the following script:

```
echo $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable')->fetchObject()->count(*);
```

But when I execute it, I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*'. How can I get around this?
>   How can I resolve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: `->count(*)` change to `->count()`

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
echo $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS rownum FROM testtable')->fetchObject()->rownum;
```

Worked for me

Comment: That's true, using an alias will work, but since you're just getting a single value still, fetchColumn still makes more sense than using fetchObject.

Answer (score 1):

Use fetchColumn when you only need to get one value.

```
echo $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable')->fetchColumn();
```

Your error is because `count(*)` would calling a method named `count` on the object with a first argument of `*`.  Just an asterisk without quotes will result in a syntax error in PHP.  You instead would need to use `$obj->{'COUNT(*)'}` to access a property with the name of `COUNT(*)`, but it's much simpler to use fetchColumn.

Comment: Also, much easier just to name the darn thing... `COUNT(*) as Num`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this? with [fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable");
echo $result->fetchColumn();
```

See example: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php#72609

Comment: When I did, I got 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string'

Comment: @coolcuber I made a mistake you need fetchColumn here. see my edit plz

Comment: @Devon sorry to say, I didn't copy your answer. I just forgot the reference and method name. See I've added the reference of php.net

Comment: OK.  It just looks odd that you had a completely different answer when you first answered the problem but put the same method in 3 minutes after I added my answer.

Comment: @Devon I agreed and I really apologize for that "I just forgot fetch__() method name here" but when I see the php.net ref. I just edit it back. Sorry for the confusion :) Hope you understand

Comment: @Devon  I started to edit my answer when coolcuber said that "When I did, I got 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string' ", then I realize I've used wrong method here :(

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the last asterisk in the `->count(*)` but even if this were fixed as Devon pointed out, it wouldn't work anyway since there is no `count()` method on what is returned by `fetchObject()`.

Refer to the documentation for fetchObject [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) and fetchColumn [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

You could try

```
echo $conn->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testtable')->fetchObject();
```

To get the whole row, but since the row has just one column, `->fetchColumn(0)` is all you need.

Comment: It's a stdClass object returned from fetchObject, there wouldn't be a class method here.

Comment: @Devon Thanks, corrected my answer and upvoted yours.